# Bad cursor color on custom edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, autocompletetextview

I tried to override the AutoCompleteTextView and the cursor in the field is now white. Because of bright gray background it is difficult to recognize them. I don't understand how it could be possible, I didn't set any custom style, the other fields are ok and show standart green cursor.

Here is my custom class:

```
public class CustomerAutoCompleteTextView extends AutoCompleteTextView {

    NewTransactionDialogFragment dialog;

    public CustomerAutoCompleteTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomerAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomerAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK &&
                event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    if(dialog!=null){
                        dialog.showFieldsOverCustomer();
                    }
        }else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER &&
                event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP){
            if(dialog!=null){
                dialog.hideKeyboard(); //this part doesn't work if I press ENTER, but it will be my other question
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyPreIme(keyCode, event);

    }


    public void setDialog(NewTransactionDialogFragment dialog){
        this.dialog=dialog;
    }
}
```

And here is my layout:

```
<my_package.CustomerAutoCompleteTextView
android:id="@+id/inputCustomer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="45dp"
android:background="@drawable/apptheme_edit_text_holo_light"
android:hint="@string/hint_customer_email"
android:cursorVisible="true"
android:singleLine="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:drawablePadding="10dp"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
android:inputType="none" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the `support-v7` `AppCompat` libraries, all of your custom views should extend their `AppCompat` counterparts.  Try extending `AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView`.

[Source](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html)

Comment: Yeah! Thank you! It was really not obviously for me. Now it works fine and my cursor is green again.

Answer (score 0):

You can set android:textCursorDrawable attribute to @null the cursor colour will be the same as your text colour.

The cursor probably changed because you change themes.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I didn't set any theme, only background, but other fields hava the same background and cursor is green. I can't set textCursorDrawable because my minSDK is 9